# Joda time, Period from millis

Tags: java, jodatime

I'm trying to set my Period object using the "millis" constructor and have all the relevant fields be updated accordingly (years, months, weeks, days, hours, minutes, seconds)

That is, using the following code:

```
mPeriod = new Period(millis, PeriodType.standard());
```

doesn't fill all the relevant fields accordingly.
only weeks and minutes (for input millis of `1325965615539`)

can someone please help me figure this thing out ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can normalize it using [`Period#normalizedStandard();`](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/apidocs/org/joda/time/Period.html#normalizedStandard%28%29)

However, there's no way `Period` can "fill in all the relevant fields", because it can't make assumptions about the number of days in months or years. The best it can do is to turn it into weeks, days, and time fields.

The Javadoc touches on this, but not in great detail:

> If the period contains years or months, then the months will be
>   normalized to be between 0 and 11. The days field and below will be
>   normalized as necessary, however this **will not overflow into the
>   months field**. Thus a period of 1 year 15 months will normalize to 2
>   years 3 months. But a period of 1 month 40 days will remain as 1 month
>   40 days.

<sup>*(Emphasis mine)*</sup>

If you need it to normalize into years and months, you need to construct the `Period` with values in those fields.

Alternatively, you could use a `Duration`:

1. Construct a [`Duration`](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/apidocs/org/joda/time/Duration.html#Duration%28long%29) with milliseconds
2. Use [`Duration#toPeriodFrom(ReadableInstant)`](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/apidocs/org/joda/time/base/BaseDuration.html#toPeriodFrom%28org.joda.time.ReadableInstant%29) to create a `Period` starting at a given instant in time (e.g. new `DateTime()`). According to the docs, this should work:

   > This conversion will determine the fields of a period accurately. The
   >   results are based on the instant millis, the chronology of the
   >   instant, the standard period type and the length of this duration.

---

Here's what `normalize()` should do to your millisecond input:

```
import org.joda.time.Period;

class Normalize {
        public static void main(String[] args) {
                Period period = new Period(1325965615539L);
                System.out.println(period);
                System.out.println(period.normalizedStandard());
        }
}

// outputs
PT368323H46M55.539S
P2192W2DT19H46M55.539S
```

Notice the second line *has* been normalized, but only up to weeks.

Comment: @DrorWeiss - It probably had an effect, but perhaps not what you were expecting. I updated my answer to clarify why.